# css: element still to wide when using box-sizing

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to display a list within a section. I'm using width/height set to 100% in combination with `box-sizing: border-box`, but for reasons I don't understand things are still to wide. The html in question looks like this:

```
<main>
    <section scrumboard="" class="scrumboard">
        <ol class="lanes">
            <li class="lane droppable">
                <h1 class="lane-title">todo</h1>
            </li>
            ....

        </ol>
    </section>
</main>
```

And the CSS:

```
html,body,main,section {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    padding: 20px;
}

 .scrumboard {
     background-color: #aaa;
 }

 .lanes {
     box-sizing: border-box;
     display: flex;
     flex-wrap: nowrap;
     font-size: 0;
     height: 100%;
     list-style-type: none;
     margin: 50px 0 0;
     padding: 0px;
 }

 .lane {
     height: 100%;
     border: 1px dashed black;
     margin: 0 5px 10px 5px;
     box-sizing: border-box;
     display: inline-block;
     text-align: center;
     flex: 1 100%;
 }

 .lane-title {
     font: 100 20px/40px 'Titillium Web';
     margin-top: -35px;
     color: #253248;
     text-transform: uppercase;
 }
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/H9qLj/2/)
So, I don't understand why the padding on the `body` element drops off at the right side and why the `li` element are to long (the border at the bottom is not visible. Any suggestions what I'm missing here ?

Comment: It doesn't drop, it overflows, and as you are using `overflow: hidden;` it hides, also you are using `box-sizing` so it will count the `padding` *inside* instead of *outside*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I should note that web browsers usually apply a `margin` on `<body>` element. Since margin is not included in calculation of `width`/`height` of a box, you have to remove that by:

```css
body { margin: 0; }
```

So that the first issue **[would be fixed](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/H9qLj/3/)**.

Second, the full-height `<li>` items are pushed down because of the `50px` margin on the top of `.lanes` element (their container).

Which you could fix that by using CSS3 [`calc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) function for the [height](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/height) of `li.lane` elements as follows:

```css
.lane {
    height: calc(100% - 50px);
}
```

**[Example Here](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/H9qLj/4/)**

Since you're using flexbox for layout purpose, using `calc()` seems fine in terms of browser support.

Comment: thnx, margins are not included in box-sizing :) I found an other solution on stackoverflow: `border-top: 50px solid rgba(0,0,0,0);` instead of the `margin 50px ...`

Comment: @JeanlucaScaljeri [That's](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/H9qLj/6/) a nice idea. Even better than `calc()` which is not supported in IE8.